# can Google Places API do a fuzzy search

Tags: search, fuzzy

Can I set Google Places API to do a fuzzy search? It seems Google map search (which use JavaScript) does that automatically, but it appears the REST API does not. I am frustrated by having to type in the accurate hotel name....any spelling errors bring up no result.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Text Search requests**,

The Google Places API Text Search Service is a web service that returns information about a set of places based on a string — for example "pizza in New York" or "shoe stores near Ottawa" or "123 Main Street". The service responds with a list of places matching the text string and any location bias that has been set.

The service is especially useful for making **ambiguous address queries** in an automated system, and non-address components of the string may match businesses as well as addresses. Examples of ambiguous address queries are incomplete addresses, poorly formatted addresses, or a request that includes non-address components such as business names.

Comment: In my case I am offering users the opportunity to retrieve specific data on a specific hotel, so they need to type in the name of the hotel they are interested in. Ambiguity in the spelling of the hotel name is the issue. Incorrect spelling, if only slight, will give 'no result'.with Google Places API.